# Overwrite Web Layer won't update Pop-Up fields using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, popup, arcgis-portal

I've deleted some fields from a feature class and re-published the feature layer to the ArcGIS Portal using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.1, however the feature class pop-up still shows the deleted fields and I have not found a way of deleting them.

I am using the "Overwrite Web Layer" option in ArcGIS Pro to re-publish the map.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

I cannot delete the existing map as it's being referenced by other users' map. I see the same issue on either feature layer or map image layer.

Comment: Following this as I'm having the same issue. Even when I published it as a new web layer to see what would happen, the pop-up fields are maintained as in the old version and I have no idea where it could be drawing the old schema properties from.

Comment: The popup definition is stored inside the Webmap json. You would have to update the webmap as well to reflect the feature service schema change.

Answer (score 0):

As Carlos suggested above, I fixed the issue weeks ago by updating the webmap json using ArcGIS Online Assistant.